# Monotonic in sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, measure-theory, algebraic-topology

Please help me prove that if  $A \subseteq B$, then $m(A) \leq m(B)$ (That $m$ is monotonic).

How would you prove this? Can we say $m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B)$ where $m^*(A \cup B) + m^*(A) = m^*(B)$? Do we need some points in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B$ be in a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ of $X$.  Then $B \cap A =  X - ((X - A) \cup (X - B))$ by De Morgan's law and so $B \cap A$ is in $\Sigma$ too (and we see $\Sigma$ is closed under intersections).  Then $B \cap (X - A\cap B) = B - A$ and so set differences are also within $\Sigma$.

Countable additivity says that if $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$, then $m(A_1) + m(A_2) = m(A_1 \cup A_2)$.  $A$ and $B-A$ are disjoint.  $m(A) + m(B-A) = m(A \cup (B - A)) = m(B)$ where the last step uses the fact $A \subseteq B$.  Because $m(B-A) \geq 0$, we see that $m(A) \leq m(B)$.

Comment: Oh I just realised you were showing this for a $\sigma$-algebra.  I'll edit with more details

Comment: Thanks. That was the idea that I had. Thanks for showing it with details with sigma algebra. I was working that one out.